# Jquery selector for table row id

Tags: jquery, selector

Cant see why cannot find a row by its id besides it exists in table.

```
var row=$('#tempo_maquina').find('#row_CMIP>A>1900-01-01>A>1900-01-01>1900-01-01');

console.log(row.length);
```

I've setup a fiddle with the html.
https://jsfiddle.net/y7qgt6vy/

Answer (score 5):

The problem is because the `>` character is used for the child selector, so you need to escape it for it to be interpreted as part of the `id`. Try this:

```
$('#tempo_maquina').find('#row_CMIP\\>A\\>1900-01-01\\>A\\>1900-01-01\\>1900-01-01');
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/y7qgt6vy/2/)

Alternatively as Pranav points out, you could use the 'attribute equals' selector:

```
$('#tempo_maquina').find('[id="row_CMIP>A>1900-01-01>A>1900-01-01>1900-01-01"]');
```